# How can I edit AndroidManifest.xml using Flutterflow.io?

Tags: flutterflow

I'm trying to use `flutter_local_notifications` and I need to add this to AndroidManifest.xml to wake up the screen when receiving a notification:

```xml
<activity
    android:showWhenLocked="true"
    android:turnScreenOn="true">
```

Easy enough with standard Flutter, but how do I do this with flutterflow.io?